# Laravel Nova, custom options belongsTo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

How I can add custom options in a belongsTo, I found another solution, but I think isn't correct/beauty

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    $rooms = array();

    $resourceId = ($request->viaResourceId) ? $request->viaResourceId : $request->resourceId;

    $event = \App\Event::where('id', $resourceId)->first();
    $rooms = array();

    foreach ($event->hotels()->get() as $hotel) {
        foreach ($hotel->roomTypes()->get() as $room) {
            $rooms[$room->id] = $hotel->name.' - '.$room->title;
        }
    }

    return [
        (new Tabs('Configuración', [
            'Tarifa' => [
                BelongsTo::make('Evento', 'event', Event::class)->required(),
                Select::make('Habitación', 'room_type_id')->options($rooms)->displayUsingLabels(),
                BelongsTo::make('Régimen', 'board', Board::class)->required(),
                Money::make('Importe', 'EUR', 'amount')->required(),
            ],
            'Fechas' => [
                Date::make('Fecha desde', 'checkin')->required()->creationRules(REQUIRED, 'after_or_equal:today'),
                Date::make('Fecha desde', 'checkout')->required()->rules(REQUIRED, 'after_or_equal:checkin'),
            ],
            'Cupo' => [
                Number::make('Ocupación', 'quota')->required()->hideFromIndex(),
                Number::make('Reservados', 'booked')->readonly()->hideFromIndex(),
            ],
            'Info Adicional' => $this->detailDataPanel(),
        ]))->withToolbar()
    ];
}
```

I want

```
Select::make('Habitación', 'room_type_id')->options($rooms)->displayUsingLabels(),
```

convert to

```
BelongsTo::make('Habitación', 'room_type_id')->options($rooms)->displayUsingLabels(),
```

I tried with relatables, but Room Types depend of the Hotels related with Event.

Comment: still no answer?