# Laravel 8 Nova: Customize Reationship BelongsToMany options, displayUsing and resolveUsing don't work

Tags: laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many, laravel-nova

In a Nova resource, I show a `BelongsToMany` Nova Field. I would want to simply concatenate (prepending) a "check pictogram" before options values of this field, if they are already attached to the Nova resource.

I've tried to use:

```
BelongsToMany::make(__('Circuits'), 'circuits', Circuit::class)->displayUsing(function ($name) {
            return '...';
        }),
```

and

```
BelongsToMany::make(__('Circuits'), 'circuits', Circuit::class)->resolveUsing(function ($name) {
            return '...';
        }),
```

But both don't work (no error, but it doesn't modify the options shown in the Field).

I've also tried [Laravel Nova, custom options belongsTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167653/laravel-nova-custom-options-belongsto) but it doesn't work (the functions `options` and `displayUsingLabels` don't modify anything - still, no error is displayed).

I should rather override `BelongsToMany` class, should I (how?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to prefix with a check or just text, etc. But we can filter out the options values by specifying, in the Nova resource, a method `setRelatableX(...) {...}`.